# Lazy Load images from HTTP on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, lazy-loading

is there also a way to lazy load images from HTTP on blackberry? thanks!

Comment: do u want to prevent too many threads error by using lazy load of images...

Comment: no sir. i simply want to load images like 3 at a time so that it wont take too much time loading, as compared to fetching images all at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

I don't if it's what you're after, but you can check out my jQuery plugin called [JAIL](http://www.sebarmeli.com/projects/jail)

that can be used for lazy loadng images in desktop and mobile sites

Comment: thanks for the response. But i dont think i can use that for blackberry apps.

Comment: ah sorry I thought you needed it for a website on mobile site